# Run C++ code in Qt Creator on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I must write some C++ on Ubuntu Linux. After many searches I found Qt Creator IDE and G++ compiler. So, the problem is: how to run a C++ program and show console black window? For example, how can I get result from this code :

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello";
    int a[5];
    cout << "Enter 5 numbers";
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
}
```

I am very in a hurry and I will be very thankful for your answer.

---

I changed code to this:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
//    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    cout<<"Hello";
    int a[5];
    cout<<"Enter 5 numbers";
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        cin>>a[i];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        cout << a[i] << " " << flush; 
//    return a.exec();
}
```

but still isn't working. I enter each number in one line, is it correct? How can I enter data for array in true way?

Answer (score 3):

Well... there is the play button that will run your application. On lowest-right part of QTCreator, there is a tab "3 application output" that will show you the output.

If you want to run the application in a console without QtCreator, go to the folder where you have your source code. There should be the executable that you can run with

```
./excutable_name
```

Comment: thanks so much,yes i saw the play button and app output windows,but i couldn't show the console window,and in app output window,for my above code,when i enter array,i doesn't show the array ! my good friend can you explain it some easier ... thank you !

Comment: Under linux you don't have a console window. It displays on your current console (QtCreator's by default). If you run step by step, then it won't display because of caching. Try std::cout << a[i] << " " << std::flush; But a the end of your application it should display everything

Answer (score 2):

There is a checkbox "Run in terminal" in the run configurations (left rim, "Projects" tab, "Run", "Run Configuration"). If you check that you get an external terminal opened, by default xterm. You can configure another terminal in the lobal setting ("Tools", "Options", "Environment", "General", "System")